# Insert 'A' just before 'f' and 'F' in a string converting them to ASCII first - JS

Tags: javascript

I have a string and I would like to insert an 'A' just before 'f' and 'F' characters throughout the string. The approach I took is to convert the string into a string[] and convert them into ascii -> which might be an overkill and add 'A' and join them back. However, I end up adding 'A' only to the beginning. Please advice.

> String: 'force be with you Forever'
>
> Output: 'Aforce be with you AForever'

```js
function addAbeforeFs(text) {
  const textSplit = text.split('');
  const smallf = 102;
  const capitalF = 70;
  const capitalA = 65;
  const asciiArray = textSplit.map((item, index) => {
    return text.charCodeAt(index)
  })
  asciiArray.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
    if (item === smallf || item === capitalF) {
      arr.splice(index - 1 < 0 ? 0 : index - 1, 0, capitalA)
    }
  })
  return asciiArray.map(item => String.fromCharCode(item)).join('')
}

console.log(addAbeforeFs('force be with you Forever'))
```

Please advice. No **replace** solutions please. Want to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: What's ASCII got to do with this? Did you mean "characters"?

Comment: Only at the beginning of a word or also in the middle, and what is when there are two `f`s (`"I like waffles?"` -> `"I like waafafles"`) ?

Comment: Yeah. I converted to an ascii

Comment: ALl throughout. waffles should be waAfAfles. Anypoint we find an f, we insert an A just before it.

Comment: Your problem is that you're editing what you're iterating over : when iterating over the first character you add an A before it because it's an f, and then the second iteration reads the second character of the string which now is an f once again. A generic solution is to use a second array to store the result of your transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a reduce if you insist?

Note you can test `item.toLowerCase() === "f"` to save some code

```js
function addAbeforeFs(text) {
  const textSplit = text.split('');
  const smallf = "f"
  const capitalF = "F"
  const capitalA = "A";

  return textSplit.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc += item === smallf || item === capitalF ? `${capitalA}${item}`:item;
    return acc;
  },"")
}

console.log(addAbeforeFs('force be with you Forever'))
```

Answer: BEFORE OP added "no replace"

```js
const addAbeforeFs = text => text.replace(/f/gi,"A$&");

console.log(addAbeforeFs('force be with you Forever'))
console.log(addAbeforeFs('Waffles'))
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. I am not looking for a replace solution. I want to know the place I am going wrong.

Comment: @a2441918 is a reduce better?

Comment: Yes please. I tried using reduce but couldnt get to work so opted for foreach

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively common bug of enumerating and modifying the same array instead of a copy.
The `arr` parameter in the `forEach` loop is the `asciiArray`.
At the first `index` 0, `capitalA` is inserted at the beginning of the array, and the first item in the array `smallf` is moved to index 1.
On the second loop, it checks the item at index 1 which is now `smallf` because of the shift from the previous loop, and `capitalA` is again inserted before `smallf`.
This continues for the rest of the indexes.

Common solution is to loop over one copy of the array, and modify another copy of the array.
Another solution for inserting and deleting parts of array, is to loop starting from the end instead of the beginning.

---

Another option without replace can be with `map` :

```js
function addAbeforeFs(text) {
  return text.split('').map(c => c === 'f' || c === 'F' ? 'A' + c : c).join('')
}

console.log(addAbeforeFs('force be with you Forever'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you are adding an item to the array while you're looping over it. Take for example your ASCII array while:

```
i:   0    1   2     3   4
a: [102, 111, 114, 99, 101, ... ]
     ^-- item
```

When your loop first begins, it starts at `item` being the first element in your array: `102`. Since 102 is equal to `smallf`, you insert `capitalA` into the current index `i`, making your array look like so:

```
i:  0    1    2    3   4    5
a: [65, 102, 111, 114, 99, 101, ... ]
```

Notice how all the values have now shifted to the right by 1 index (to accommodate the new value just inserted). Your loop then continues onto the next index in your array:

```
i:   0   1   2     3   4    5
a: [65, 102, 111, 114, 99, 101, ... ]
          ^-- item
```

Now on the second iteration of your loop we are again pointing to the same `102` we just saw! **This is the main problem with your current code**. Rather than looking at 102 again, you want to *skip* this item. So you might be wondering, how do you skip an item in a `.forEach()` loop? - You can't. Instead, you can use a regular for loop and skip the values by incrementing the index once you find a `102`. This way your code will perform the following jump:

```
i:   0   1   2     3   4    5
a: [65, 102, 111, 114, 99, 101, ... ]
         ^    ^-- item  
         |__ skipped as we just looked at this number.
```

Other than adding in this small, change, your insert logic is slightly wrong. Rather than inserting at the previous index using `i-1`, you can insert at the current index `i` - allowing you to remove the ternary:

```
asciiArray.splice(i, 0, capitalA);
```

See code comments and example below of your modified code (commented lines = modified lines):

```js
function addAbeforeFs(text) {
  const textSplit = text.split('');
  const smallf = 102;
  const capitalF = 70;
  const capitalA = 65;
  const asciiArray = textSplit.map((item, index) => {
    return text.charCodeAt(index)
  });
  for(let i = 0; i < asciiArray.length; i++) { // Change to normal for loop so we can skip indexes easily
    const item = asciiArray[i];
    if (item === smallf || item === capitalF) {
      asciiArray.splice(i, 0, capitalA); // insert at the current index
      i++; // go to the next item (which will be 102 or 70), but then your for loop's i++ will skip/jump over this item. As a result, you'll skip the next item
    }
  }
  return asciiArray.map(item => String.fromCharCode(item)).join('')
}

console.log(addAbeforeFs('force be with you Forever'))
```

Another solution to this is to loop through your array backwards. This would just require needing to change your for loop. This works because when you insert you will push all indexes after `i` up, but those under `i` will remain. Meaning that you won't loop back into the item you can shifted across:

```
for (let i = asciiArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Loop backwards through your array
  const item = asciiArray[i];
  if (item === smallf || item === capitalF) {
    asciiArray.splice(i, 0, capitalA); // insert at the current index
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `replace` like so :

```js
const str = "force be with you Forever";

console.log(str.replace(/([fF])/g, "A$1"))
```

Comment: Thanks.I am not looking for a replace solution. I want to know the place I am going wrong